# To what mourn refers in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms, interpretation

"Her words like the mountain, stood lonely and lofty
With her face like a daydream and her hair like the shawl
Worn by a mourner, who steals away softly
**From those that would have him mourn nothing at all**"

Does it mean that those who was stolen:
A)Would have nothing to mourn for him? (Probably because he stole them)
B)Would have nothing to mourn? (They just have nothing to mourn)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Would have him VERB...* is by itself an idiom that is difficult for a learner, because the verbs *would* and *have* do not have their usual meanings.

- *would* is used in its oldest sense, which is "desire" or "wish". In most contexts this use is archaic, but in this particular idiom, with *have*, it is still encountered occasionally.
- *have* does not mean "possess" but is used in the causative sense, as when we say "I will have him fix my car".
- When you put the two together as (approximately) *desire to cause [him to] mourn* it has a deontic (obligation) sense: roughly, "believe that [he should] mourn"

In addition, the verb *steal* here is also used in a sense you may not be familiar with. It is not the transitive verb meaning "take unlawfully" but an  intransitive verb meaning to "move quietly, without being noticed"

So the whole may be paraphrased:

> ... her hair like the shawl worn by a mourner who moves away quietly from those who believe that he should not mourn anything at all.

What exactly that is intended to signify is LitCrit, and beyond the scope of this site--which is fortunate, because really Van Zandt is building his song as a sequence of provocative images rather than a coherent narrative.

Many of his lyrics have this sort of archaic diction, which derives from the 17th and 18th century ballads surviving in the US folk tradition.